# Keep getting 1.#INF as my output

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double calc(int a, int b);

int main()
{
    int n1, n2;

    cout << "Enter a number for a: ";
    cin >> n1;
    cout << "Enter a number for b: ";
    cin >> n2;

    cout << calc(n1, n2) << endl;

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;

}

double calc(int a, int b)
{
    double s;
    s = (a) / ((sqrt(a / b)));
    return s;
}
```

This program is meant to check whether the two integers are greater than zero. If it is it will calcualte the formula. Otherwise if one of the integers is zero or less than zero it will not return anything and exit the program. 
My question here is that no matter what I input for a and b, i keep getting 1.#INF as the output and I have no idea why. I've checked the formula in a seperate program and it worked fine.
Any ideas?

Comment: Which numbers are you entering?

Comment: What happens for a = 4, b = 1? My guess is you're entering numbers where a < b, causing a / b to return 0.

Comment: Are you developing in an IDE? If so, use the debugger; set breakpoints, examine variables. You will soon see the problem. If not, start doing so & you will ask far fewer questions on this site. There, that's taught you how to fish.

Comment: When you divide 2 integers, the result is also an integer, so there is not decimal part (Example: 3/2 = 1). So you have to manually cast variables a and b to double.

Comment: You may find this article of interest: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/02/21/10395734.aspx

Comment: "This program is meant to check whether the two integers are greater than zero..." I don't see that in your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, you are operating with `int` numbers:

```
s = (a) / ((sqrt(a / b)));
```

If `a` is less then `b`, then `a/b` (both are integers, remember, so the fractional part of the result will simply be lost) will be equal to 0, which leads to division by 0. You need to cast one of the numbers to double:

```
s = (a) / ((sqrt(static_cast<double>(a) / b)));
```

Comment: This fixed my problem. The comment by iqstatic also helped my problem but I don't understand the difference between the two solutions.

Answer (score 1):

`sqrt` takes and returns a double. When you call it with integer arguments it will be converted in a double, and will thus get the value of infinity.

change your function signature to:

```
double calc(double a, double b);
```

and declare n1 and n2 as double.

Answer (score 0):

You say that the function will exit the program when one of the integers are 0 or less, but where?

Try to check them like this:

Additionally, you should have a check whether a is greater than b

```
double calc(int a, int b)
{
    double s;
    if(a <= 0) exit(-1);
    if(b <= 0) exit(-1);
    if(a < b)  exit(-1);
    s = (a) / ((sqrt(a / b)));
    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are having problems with infinity. For it use `isinf`. Here is some sample usage:

```
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf */
#include <math.h>       /* isinf, sqrt */

    int main()
    {
      printf ("isinf(-1.0/0.0)  : %d\n",isinf(-1.0/0.0));
      printf ("isinf(sqrt(-1.0)): %d\n",isinf(sqrt(-1.0)));
      return 0;
    }
```

output:

> isinf(-1.0/0.0) : 1 isinf(sqrt(-1.0): 0